# How to define printing options of a php generated pdf file?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I generate a PDF file from PHP with TCPDF classes. I would like to count the number of copies, because the original PDF file have to print once and the others have a header like second copy, third copy.

Is there any solution for this, or how can I check it after the user download the PDF?

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand: You would like the pdf which the user has downloaded to automatically change each time they print it, or would you like to send them a different pdf each time they ask for one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect what the user is doing in the browser with PHP. You detect user interaction with the browser with JavaScript but I am fairly certain you cannot detect how many copies they are printing for security purposes.

Since the PDF is generated with PHP you can have a form saying how many copies they want and then generate one large PDF with all the copies and heading pages. They print this document once and get all the copies they need.